# Some mouse events are not being detected in a portion of the screen

Tags: mouse, 23.04

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 23.04 and I ran into a very weird issue. Some mouse events, such as clicks and drags, are not being detected in a specific corner of the screen (top-right). But, for example, movement events are working fine and the cursor is shown. I have made a short video to show this behaviour: https://file.io/5WSSDNg3p6hN

I tried with both touchpad and mouse. If I attach an external monitor, the problem is still present in the primary screen, whatever it is. The external monitor is larger than the laptop's screen, and the non-working spot is not anymore in the corner but at the same distance that it would be on the laptop.

I am on an Asus N750JK. Kernel is 6.2.0-20. Everything worked fine before updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related with the Ubuntu AppIndicator extension, which displays the applications extensions in the top-right corner. After disabling the extension and rebooting, the issue was no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue. The top right screen clicks doesn't work.
This includes mouse clicks on every app top right section like X button, minimize and maximize but even lower on chrome for example - can't add more than 6-7 tabs when it reaches the right section. tried on slack same issue clicks not working on top right section.

your file is deleted BTW. couldn't download.

Comment: mmm, at least I'm glad I'm not alone with this. I tried to rollback to the kernel that I was previously using, but the problem is still there

Comment: it seems that in order to report a bug on Ubuntu's Launchpad bug sections you need to specify a related package. How can we proceed?

Answer (score 0):

> /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/appIndicator.js

So, simply make a backup of it - appIndicator.js.BAK = no more ugly indicators.

And don't forget to restart the machine/session for changes to take effect ;)

just rename that .js file and restart. the caveat is you lose the app indicators in the top right corner but the area is now clickable.

I terminated to the path, did an ls to make sure the appindicator.js file was there and did a sudo
`mv appIndicator.js appIndicator.bak`